# PyQt4 nested classes - "RuntimeError: underlying C/C++ object has been deleted"

Tags: python, pyqt4

I'm trying to build a cool app, but it seems I lack some knowledge. Read lots of infos and examples in internet, but it doesn't help:
[Understanding the "underlying C/C++ object has been deleted" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002895/understanding-the-underlying-c-c-object-has-been-deleted-error)

---

Ok, here what I do:

I create central widget from my *main.py*, which works fine and I don't post it here fully:

```
self.rw = ReportWidget()
self.setCentralWidget(self.rw)
```

And here is my central widget - *report.py*:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class ReportWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ReportWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setup_ui()

    def setup_ui(self):
        report = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        report.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)

        head = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        add_label = QtGui.QLabel(u"Add")
        head.addWidget(add_label)

        report.addLayout(head)

        area = QtGui.QScrollArea()
        area.setWidgetResizable(True)
        area.setEnabled(True)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        area.setWidget(widget)
        report.addWidget(area)

        self.s = layout

        # trying to create first line:
        first_line = Line(self)
        self.s.addWidget(first_line)        
        first_line.set_controls(True, False)

        head = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        ok = QtGui.QPushButton(u"Calculate")

        head.addWidget(ok)
        report.addLayout(head)
```

Continued from the same file *report.py*:

```
class Line(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Line, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setup_ui(parent)

    def setup_ui(self, parent):
        add_button = QtGui.QPushButton()
        add_button.setObjectName("add_button")

        self.add_button = add_button
        self.layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(line)
        self.layout.addWidget(add_button)

    def set_controls(self, add_button=True, remove_button=True):
        self.add_button.setEnabled(add_button)
```

Thus, running *main.py* raises `RuntimeError: underlying C/C++ object has been deleted` error on the last piece of code where I try to `setEnabled` parameter to new button, as if it was never created or bound anywhere.

It seems I have some design flaw. Maybe it's wrong idea to have different classes in one file or else? Or maybe I don't quite control which widget has which parent and how layouts work.

---

Thank you for reading. Have a nice day!

Comment: It seems everything is ok, only except `self.layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(line)`. Where does `line` come from? Perhaps it should be `self.layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)`.

Comment: Also, don't use `self.layout` as name. `layout()` is a common method for widgets. It returns the current layout of the widget. You're overriding it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone who tried to answer! Unfortunately no one said what a bunch of crap I wrote! *smile*

My `line` is already a widget and I don't need to create itself inside itself. All I had to do is to create layout inside `setup_ui` and add widgets to it. Finally it looks like:

```
class Line(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Line, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setup_ui(parent)

    def setup_ui(self, parent):
        line = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)

        add_button = QtGui.QPushButton()
        add_button.setObjectName("add_button")

        line.addWidget(add_button)

        # to get reference from outside
        self.add_button = add_button

    def set_controls(self, add_button=True, remove_button=True):
        self.add_button.setEnabled(add_button)
```

Special thanks to [nymk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/779412/nymk) and [Avaris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/843822/avaris)!

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce an error with the code you showed us (apart from an error about the variable `line` not being defined in `Line.setup_ui`).   If I replaced `line` with `self`, I got no error.

However, I could get a crash if I set `line` to a `QWidget` that I created and didn't keep a reference to.   In other words, I added

```
    line = QtGui.QWidget()
```

to `Line.setup_ui`, and found that this crashed on the same line of code you reported, complaining that the wrapped C/C++ object had been deleted.

Comment: Thank you for trying to reproduce error, but it wasn't really possible because I posted only bit of code. Nevertheless your idea to play with 'line' and 'self' prompted me to the solution.